# How to pass json object into json array

Tags: java, json

I am new to J2EE and JSON.
I am using `jsonArray.put(jsonObject)` for adding a json object to a json array but its showing error message:

> The method put(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONArray.

The library I am using for json is `org.json.simple.*`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to put new stuff into an array is called `add`. So:

```
jsonArray.add(jsonObject)
```

should work.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) for details.